# I got Altruist and Benefactor on the same question

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, badges, bounty-badges

I set up a bounty [on another person's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138393/exception-when-trying-to-upload-file-from-flex-to-rails-using-paperclip/3160374#3160374) and awarded the same within 7 days, and received my `Investor` and `Altruist` badges a couple of days back. The badges were awarded retrospectively - the bounty was created and awarded a couple of days before the badges were implemented.

Just now SO surprised [me saying](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165297/amarghosh) that I received a `Benefactor` badge for the same question. I thought the `Benefactor` was for awarding bounties on my own questions. I've never started a bounty on any of my questions let alone award them.

I guess it's a bug. For what it's worth, I got my `Electorate` badge (my first golden one) along with it. They came together; it said - *"you've earned a Benefactor and one more badge: check your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165297/amarghosh)"*

My question is, how do I exploit this bug to get a Gold or at least a Silver badge ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, it was my fault 16 people total were affected on SO, this is fixed now.

Comment: Cheers... and that was fast..!